# Choppy scrolling in chrome with big background images

Tags: css, google-chrome, scroll, background-image

I've created a web page, and it has 7 six sections with huge background images using `background-size: cover;`. It works fine in all browsers except Google Chrome (All versions/All platforms). When I try scrolling the page in google chrome or click on its links (which they also scroll the page using $.scrollTo) the page gets choppy and laggy and it scrolls slowly and uses 100% CPU.

I've uploaded the page so you can test it: http://baaemail.com/beta (I'll remove the page later). Even IE9/10 is fine, but chrome gets choppy.

The page has several "scroll" events bound to it and I have tried disabling the javascript altogether but it doesn't get better so its not from the scroll events.

I'm using `background-size: cover` because it shapes the photo exactly like I want it to and I want the image to be fixed that's why I can't use other methods like using `img` tag instead of backgrounds.

What should I do?
thanks.

Comment: A good portion of the time Google Chrome will act like this. Honestly, it runs perfectly fine for me. My only suggestion is to try to compress the images.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found for myself for a website with similar behaviour was to add `background-repeat:no-repeat` css property for those divs containing huge background images.

You can also check if you have a background image for `body` or `html` that is repeated, for me the big problem was a repeated pattern image that interfered considerably with google chrome's scrolling performance.

Also if you're using CSS transitions on those "slides" you should check that those are not assigned to "all". If you're having a transition only for the "left" property there is no point assigning it for "all".

I'm not sure if this alone will help you but it is always a good practice to compress your images and your scripts.

This stuff did the trick for me. Hope it helps.